# Is it illegal to block people on Instagram?

Tags: discrimination

Is blocking certain people while allowing everybody else to view some content discrimination and violate anti-discrimination laws.Also is not being able to consume information available on a public platform a violation against  right to freedom.

EDIT: I ask this question to challenge the design of the social media sites, not to sue anybody who blocks me. ; -)

Comment: Are you asking about United States law, or some other country?

Comment: Any democratic country in general because their laws should be almost same in this context.

Comment: @HarshitBujarBaruah "Any democratic country in general because their laws should be almost same in this context." not true at all.

Answer (score 3):

> Is blocking certain people while allowing everybody else to view some content discrimination

Yes.

> and violate anti-discrimination laws

Probably not, at least in the US.

There is no federal law prohibiting "discrimination" in general. There are specific laws regarding discrimination against certain groups in certain contexts. They would probably not apply to an individual determining who is allowed to view their social media posts.

That said, there are some specific contexts where this might be illegal. They would generally involve non-personal use of the account. The courts recently ruled that Donald Trump may not block people on his Twitter account, because he's using it in an official presidential capacity rather than just his individual capacity. Also, racial discrimination in housing is illegal, so if you're selling your house and you block all black people from viewing your house photos, that would probably be illegal as well.

> Also is not being able to consume information available on a public platform a violation against right to freedom.

I'm not sure what you think a "right to freedom" would entail. But I don't think you have the right to demand that a person allow you to access their social media accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think new technologies like social media poses many challenges to our legal structure. Regarding right to freedom , for example ,  if you stop me from watching a movie even if I am willing to pay for it should be a violation , but then you not allowing me to enter your home should not be. In the virtual world though , is social media like a broadcast of your life or your virtual home ?